# Uso de várias instancias do Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google, google-maps-api-3

Preciso desenhar várias vezes um map e tenho uma função que carrega o mapa e que é a primeira a ser invocada ao abrir a página. Segue o corpo da função:

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom:  8,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-15.8307603,-47.9088141),

   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

    myService.clearTimeouts();
 for(var j = 0; j < $kinvey.arrayIdColetor.length;  j++){ 
   drawLatLong(j, $kinvey.arrayIdColetor);          
 }

 $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map);
```

Após carregado o mapa, o usuário pode selecionar um item de um combobox para mudar os dados do mapa de acordo com o item selecionado. Para isso utilizo a seguinte função:

```
function showMapSelected(a, arrayIdColetor) {
  $scope.map = null;
  resetScopeData();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom:  8,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-15.8307603,-47.9088141),

   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }); 

  drawLatLong(a, arrayIdColetor);          

  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map);
}
```

Como vocês podem notar, quando crio o mapa pela primeira vez utilizo:

```
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map);
```

depois quando o usuario seleciona um item no combobox eu recrio o mapa novamente:

```
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map);
```

Isso está correto com relação ao desempenho? Quando faço isso, estou criando várias instancias para o map ou não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta re-instanciando o mapa, você pode simplesmente limpar o mapa e montar todos os elementos novamente.

Você pode instanciar o mapa 1 vez, depois ir gerenciando os elementos dentro dele.

Por exemplo, remover todos os markers do maps

```
// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setMapOnAll(null);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
```

[Veja exemplos aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)